# Mongoose giving error for NOT required Geo spatial field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using `Mongoose Schema` and simplified version looks like:

```
const newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location:{
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Point',
      enum: ['Point']
    },
    coordinates: [Number],
  }
});

const newModel = mongoose.model('NewModel', newSchema);
```

When I try to save a new document using this schema:

```
newModel.create({
  "name": "Default name"
});
```

It is giving

```
error: 
"Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5e8ed5ddf4781c24d0836b6e'), location: { type: \"Point\" },
 name:\"Default name\"} Point must be an array or object"
```

However, when I fill the location field, it works well. I am wondering why Schema checking for the NOT required field.

Comment: use strict:false property to make it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var GeoJSON = require('mongoose-geojson-schema');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location:mongoose.Schema.Types.GeoJSON
});

const newModel = mongoose.model('NewModel', newSchema);
```

and create data like:

```
newModel.create({
  name: "Default name",
   location: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
        }
});
```

actually the problem occur due to you specified the default type is Point (that pushed by mongoose always if null or not specified) but you did't pass coordinates corresponding, and the point should be with coordinate

Comment: So, I always have to fill GeoJSON field even if it is not required?

Comment: Sorry for asking it in comment. But, I have another  GeoJSON field of (Array Type, also NOT require)] and it doesn't give any errors. Does array work differently?

Comment: So, I always have to fill GeoJSON field even if it is not required? 
no, not necessary.

Comment: just remove the      default:  point 
form your schema will also be resolve your problem.

Comment: i just mentioend GeoJsom Schema Because GeoJSON accept all kind of  geographic points and polygons. 

like you can use same schema as:
type: 'Polygon',
  coordinates: [[
    [-111, 31],
    [-202, 51],
    [-212, 22],
    [-72, 7],
    [-109, 41]
  ]]

Comment: follow link for more refernce: